# Receiving data from a BLE device to a raspberry Pi3

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

I never used a raspberry pi before and I have a project part of which includes receiving data from a BLE blood pressure device over Bluetooth to a raspberry pi 3. I can pair the device to my raspberry but I have no idea what to do next. I need to be able to receive the measurements in my raspberry please help and thank you in advance.
PS: the device I'm trying to use is very similar to this one:
https://ibb.co/71365k5

Thanks for your answers, I have tried "Gatt" and "Gatttool" but the problem is after pairing the device is meant to send the measurement to its application on an android phone, without it I cannot read the blood measurement characteristic or it just does not exist.
[image: this is the gattool list but it's almost identical for the gatt menu]

Comment: The simplest way to start with BLE on Raspbian is using NOBLE (https://github.com/noble/noble). You can also install Windows 10 IoT on Raspberry Pi 3 and use Windows UWP BLE API.

Comment: If you are looking for a quick way to explore the data (which will be [GATT](https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy/gatt) format) you can use Chromium on the RPi by going to the url `chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices` and the scan and inspect

Comment: If you're using a version of BlueZ that supports hcitool and gatttool then have a look at my answer here which gives steps to read pressure data from a similar BPM:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62201486/why-i-cant-get-the-ble-indication-response-in-raspberry-pi-with-a-bpm-sensor

Answer (score 0):

Linux uses BlueZ as a default bluetooth stack. It exposes DBus APIs for implementing software using Bluetooth.

If you don't want to use this API directly, which can sometimes feel a bit low level you have many libraries that wrap it, such as https://github.com/getsenic/gatt-python that also comes with examples.

All other solutions requires replacing the Bluetooth stack on Linux and hence your other existing Bluetooth pairings to the system will stop working.

Comment: thanks for your answer I am trying right now